# How to Connect to .geodatabase Replica Created File by ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, sqlite, replication

I am able to create Two Way Replica from ArcGIS Server 10.4.1 which has a Feature service containing only one Feature Class( `Transformers` feature class) and I am getting a file like
`_ags_data{01D644C0D8F0434DA6E65607141EC0EC}.geodatabase` in ArcGIS Server directory `C:\arcgisserver\directories\arcgisoutput\Test_MapServer` after creating the Replica.

Now I would like to check this file in an ArcMap session. I tried to connect to it through Database Connection tool but there is not any support for SQLLite on there. I also tried this [link](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/databases/connect-sqlite.htm) to Connect to SQLite from ArcGIS for Desktop but it says that the file must have the extension `.sqlite` (or .SQLITE or .SQLite) and not `.geodatabase`

Can you please let me know if there is a way to see the actual data in the `_ags_data{01D644C0D8F0434DA6E65607141EC0EC}.geodatabase` through ArcMap? I already tried to open the file by SQLLite Studio but the Feature class `Transformers` table in empty! so where are the actual attributes?

Answer (score 1):

The .geodatabase file you have is called a runtime geodatabase. In ArcMap 10.3.x and up, there's a tool called "[copy-runtime-geodatabase-to-file-geodatabase](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/copy-runtime-geodatabase-to-file-geodatabase.htm)", use that to convert it to a file Geodatabase and then open that in ArcMap.